# Flutter override Textfield up / down key behavior

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking for a way to override the behavior of flutters Textfiend up/down keys.

Currently they move the cursor to the beginning or end of the textfield.

I would like to change this behavior. I am open to any possibilities.

I looked into wrapping the Textfield with a RawKeyboardListener however the up / down key events still fall through to the Textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interesting question for Saturday, spent my free time for that :)
Found out that we can get UP and DOWN event for any key.
Example below move cursor to 3 letters back when up-arrow pressed.

[image]

The code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: KeyboardListener(),
    );
  }
}

class KeyboardListener extends StatefulWidget {
  KeyboardListener();

  @override
  _RawKeyboardListenerState createState() => _RawKeyboardListenerState();
}

class _RawKeyboardListenerState extends State<KeyboardListener> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode _textNode = FocusNode();
  String _keyPressed = 'Key pressed code: ';

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_textNode);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Search Item")),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          RawKeyboardListener(
            focusNode: _textNode,
            key: UniqueKey(),
            onKey: handleKey,
            child: TextField(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              controller: _controller,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
          Text(_keyPressed),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  handleKey(RawKeyEvent key) {
    if (key.runtimeType.toString() == 'RawKeyUpEvent') {
      RawKeyEventDataAndroid data = key.data as RawKeyEventDataAndroid;
      String _keyCode;
      _keyCode = data.keyCode.toString();
      print(_keyCode);
      if (_keyCode == '19') {
        print('up pressed');
        _controller.selection =
            TextSelection.collapsed(offset: _controller.text.length - 3);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like the solution I already tried. The problem was even though the cursor showed the correct place TextField was having a race condition to set the cursor position. So while visually it looked correct if you tried to type after it would type in the wrong place. Does your code have that problem too?

Comment: You are right, thank you. Fixed this problem by adding
key: UniqueKey(),
for TextField and for RawKeyboardListener. Updated answer and animation :)